# Handling manipulation of array objects visualized by images in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array of objects which are visualized using images from a cdn. 
Lets say I have the array below where all objects have different images.

`[x, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

When I remove object x, vue  reuses the component and just updates the data within. All images are now redownloaded because component x has the data from component 1, 1 has the data from 2 etc.

I'm wondering if there is some smooth way to not redownload all images over and over every time there has been a change in the array.

**Edit: general html for the question:**

KittyContainer:

`<div v-for="kitty in kitties">
    <KittyComponent :kitty="kitty"/>
</div>`

KittyComponent:

`<div id="kittycomponent">
    <img :src="'https://cdn.somekittyimgsite.abc/kitty/'+kitty.id+'.svg'">
</div>`

Comment: Could you write your HTML please?

Comment: Updated with the html related to the question for ya! :)

Comment: Could you try out to use a simple v-for and wrap the images in it without a component and test if that still refreshes each time?

Comment: I need to use the component for other things though, but i suppose that would have been a good solution for only showing the image.

Comment: Ok well was just curious if that would have solved the issue, i suggest you to ask the question under the tag `vuejs` since `vuejs2` gets nearly no views

Comment: Ah okay, thank you!

Comment: Try adding `:key="kitty.id"` to your `v-for`. That should give Vue.js enough information to remove/add elements as needed, instead of patching elements in place.